# How to simplify inputs for a decoder in verilog hdl

Tags: boolean, verilog, decoder, quartus, truthtable

I'm making a decoder for an FPGA. The verilog code compiles, but the switches don't do anything. I quadruple-checked the pin assignments, and they are correct, so I guess there are some logic problems with my code.

The truth table is:

```
enable  p  a1  a0  y0  y1  y2  y3  
0       0  0   0   1   0   0   0
0       0  0   1   0   1   0   0
0       0  1   0   0   0   1   0
0       0  1   1   0   0   0   1
0       1  0   0   0   1   1   1
0       1  0   1   1   0   1   1
0       1  1   0   1   1   0   1
0       1  1   1   1   1   1   0
1       x  x   x   x   z   z   z
```

This is my code:

```
module decoder2x4( 
input enable,
input p,
input [1:0] a,
output [3:0] y
);

assign y[0] = (( ~p & ~a[1] & ~a[0]) | (~a[1] & a[0]) |(a[1] & ~a[0]) |     ( p & a[1] & a[0]) ) & ~enable;
assign y[1] = (( ~p & ~a[1] & a[0]) | ( p & ~a[1] & ~a[0]) |( p & a[1] & ~a[0])| ( p & a[1] & a[0])) & ~enable;
assign y[2] = (( ~p & a[1] & ~a[0]) | ( p & ~a[1] & ~a[0]) |( p & ~a[1] & a[0])| ( p & a[1] & a[0])) & ~enable;
assign y[3] = (( ~p & a[1] & a[0]) | ( p & ~a[1] & ~a[0]) |( p & ~a[1] & a[0])| ( p & a[1] & ~a[0])) & ~enable;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not the way you use HDL code, unless it is a school assignment.

I have copied this from the work Pierre.Vriens did to you table:

```
enable  p  a1  a0  y0  y1  y2  y3  
0       0  0   0   1   0   0   0
0       0  0   1   0   1   0   0
0       0  1   0   0   0   1   0
0       0  1   1   0   0   0   1
0       1  0   0   0   1   1   1
0       1  0   1   1   0   1   1
0       1  1   0   1   1   0   1
0       1  1   1   1   1   1   0
1       x  x   x   x   z   z   z   <<< Probably a typo here
```

The bottom line is a bit special so I use an `if` for that. The reset we can put in a case:

```
always @( * )
begin
   if (enable)
      {y0, y1, y2, y3} = 4'hz; // **
   else
      case ( {p, a1, a0 } )
      3'b000 : {y0, y1, y2, y3} = 4'b1000;
      3'b001 : {y0, y1, y2, y3} = 4'b0100;
      3'b010 : {y0, y1, y2, y3} = 4'b0010;
      3'b011 : {y0, y1, y2, y3} = 4'b0001;
      3'b100 : {y0, y1, y2, y3} = 4'b0111;
      3'b101 : {y0, y1, y2, y3} = 4'b1011;
      3'b110 : {y0, y1, y2, y3} = 4'b1101;
      3'b111 : {y0, y1, y2, y3} = 4'b1110;                   
      endcase
end // always
```

Note that this copies the orignal table as much as possible, which reduced the possibilities of errors. An editor with column editing helps a lot!

<sub>** I assume you want all outputs to be 'z'. In your table you have xzzz.</sub>